# HTML jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}' ERROR

Tags: html, flask, web

I created a local server via Flask using Pycharm. But I want to create a dynamic link and this link will be a link to other websites. When I want to give a direct link, it tries to connect on my own server. But I don't want this, I want to access websites such as spotify, youtube. After some research, I found a code similar to the code below. But I am getting an error message.

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

**MY HTML CODE IS HERE**

```
<dd>
    <a href = {{ url_for('go_outside_flask_variable', variable={{music_link}} ) }}>Link</a>
</dd>
```

**MY PYTHON CODE IS HERE**

```
@app.route('/go_outside_flask/<variable>')
def go_outside_flask_method(variable):
    redirect(variable, code=302)
```

Note: Music link is like "open.spotify/tracks/*****"

Answer (score 1):

It is caused due to the variable={{music_link}}

You could try doing this
Html

```html
  <a href = {{ url_for('go_outside_flask_method', variable="{}".format(music_link) ) }}>Link</a>
```

Python

```py
@app.route("/test")
def testing():
  return render_template("test.html", music_link = 134955)

@app.route('/go_outside_flask/<variable>')
def go_outside_flask_method(variable):
    return redirect(variable, code=302)
```

Output

```
Link that have an address of (/go_outside_flask/134955)
```

**---Edit to fit the need---**

```
open.spotify.com/track/1QZRCi2Z1DQQaR6bGAzhtN
```

Now if you want to only redirect to this link just do

HTML

```html
<a href = "{{music_link}}">Link</a>
```

Python

```py
@app.route("/help")
def helping():
  return render_template("testerer.html", music_link = "https://open.spotify.com/track/2q3LzfknBzye3xXjgiJBjS?si=pzB7JVqDS0-5Gel18Jm9VQ&utm_source=copy-link&context=spotify%3Aplaylist%3A37i9dQZF1DXcZQSjptOQtk")
```

Comment: The error is caused due to jinja being strict on it's nesting rules. You can't start another brackets inside a bracket like {{ {{variable}} }} but you could work around it using format.

Comment: I did it like you comment but. When i click the link button , the url chanced like http://127.0.0.1:5000/go_outside_flask/open.spotify.com/track/1QZRCi2Z1DQQaR6bGAzhtN but i want to go open.spotify.com/track/1QZRCi2Z1DQQaR6bGAzhtN to only this website.

Comment: So the link should be just {{music_link}}?

Comment: Yes and it is dynamic link.

Comment: I updated the answer try to look for the bottom part if it fits your needs~

Comment: Now i did it like you said  just redirected http://127.0.0.1:5000/open.spotify.com/track/3PCrufS6uFrm7Q6ArBW1nf, how can i get rid of from local ?

Comment: May I see how you assign your music_link variable? Cause mine is working fine with return render_template("your.html", music_link = "open.spotify.com/track/1QZRCi2Z1DQQaR6bGAzhtN")

Comment: music_link = music_link_finder(music_name=music_name)
                    response = make_response(
                        render_template("homepage/homepage.html", music_name=music_name, music_artist=music_artist,
                                        person_mood=person_mood, music_link=music_link)

Comment: If you print(music_link) is there a 127.0.0.1:5000/ there? If so I think it is a problem with how music_link_finder generates the link?

Comment: I figured out. I add the top of url 'https:/' and solve the problem. Thank four your afford!